# SQLSERVER 2008 R2 replication error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication

i have a problem with replication. 
my sql server shows me in log : 3 errors skipped while submit replication.
but how to see records where problems appear ?
:'(
thk in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in exploring the differences you should use either a query or the tablediff utility to find the differences between your publisher and subscriber.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx

Comment: i agree about diff software; but in my case its not really easy cause someone in paris can delete one row, or create it or update it; and someone in tokyo too. so i dont know what is the true information. See query where error appeaurs help me a lot.